# How to convert + 3.3 V, 5 MHz square wave into + 100V, - 100V bipolar square wave?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, mosfet, pcb

I have generated 3.3 V, 5 MHz square wave by STM32, and I have 100 V and - 100 V power supply. How can I convert the square wave into bipolar square wave? The load is an ultrasonic probe, so I may only needs a few milliamps of current.
[image: sketch]

Comment: Suppose you can afford to waste 20% of the total period in transitions between \$+100\:\text{V}\$ and \$-100\:\text{V}\$. This means you have \$40\:\text{ns}\$ to allocate for two transitions, so \$20\:\text{ns}\$ each. Suppose your probe has only \$1\:\text{pF}\$ of capacitance. (Very small, very likely higher.) Then you'd need \$10\:\text{mA}\$ to drive it. If the capacitance is higher, you'd need more. We need technical details on the probe. One cannot just offer a generic design that works with any transducer in any medium, blind-folded. Dealing with nature doesn't work that way.

Comment: I don't have detailed electrical parameters.  I am using a 5MHz Dual-crystal Straight Probe for thickness measurement.

Comment: You may need to plan in some experimental time, then. When we face a project with unknowns, those unknowns are pulled right to the front of the project and everything else is set aside. Then experiments are designed and performed and then results are evaluated (argued about, at times.) The dust settles and we have what we need and the unknown becomes a known and we move to the next unknown until all of them are considered to be "resolved." At that point, good design can happen. I *love* Spehro's 'good catch' answer, except for one thing. Still have no idea what power supply design is required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I will try to measure the capacitance of the probe.

Comment: You can consider at least two scenarios for the transducer, I think. Unloaded and loaded. (Unless both are the same.) I'm not familiar with dual-crystal straight probes for thickness measurements. But it sounds to me as though there is a loaded situation where some non-air material's thickness is being measured. If so, you may want to work through at least two (maybe more) testing scenarios.

Comment: Crucial to the complexity is whether the frequency is fixed and you can resonate the transducer's capacitance with an inductor, or whether you want to swing the frequency over an octave or more during operation. That will affect the drive current you need by an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: Do you mean to connect an inductor in parallel with the probe? I don't know much about this. How can I calculate the required inductance?

Answer (score 4):

Your English is fine.

For probe drive up to about 1A and in the MHz, you can use a [TC6320](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/TC6320) from Microchip (née Supertex) and driver chip.

[image]

For ultrasound beam forming and such like there are driver chips that can handle many channels, but they are proprietary and expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the chip recommended. I am using a Dual-crystal Straight Probe for thickness measurement. My current plan is to directly amplify and filter the echo, and then observe the waveform with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Good pick, it's been the component I had chosen for [my design](http://un0rick.cc/un0rick), along with a MD1210 upstream..